# How can ECMAScript 2015 be used in node.js v4.2.1 without strict mode being enabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't want to use `"use strict"` but I do want ES6. How can this be done?

Comment: in nodejs, much of ES2015 works without the "use strict" kludge. Is there something in particular not working for you?

Comment: Why in the world would you not want to use strict mode? I can understand not wanting to write it at the top of every file, but there are ways around that other than just not using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node.js, you can use ES6 by default or using some runtime flag.
You don't have to use strict mode.

See https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/